# How to get dynamic textbox value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created dynamic textbox. So the textbox id's are like txt1, txt2, txt3.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lst.rows.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("txt"+ i).value;
}
```

It is not showing the textbox value. whereas if i hard code like below then it work.

```
   document.getElementById("txt0").value;
```

Kindly help me to get dynamic textbox value in javascript.

Comment: Did you debug what "txt"+i is?

Comment: When are you executing this code and where is the dynamic textbox created?

Comment: did you log the result in the console ?

Comment: I have implemented Jquery to get value like below                                $("#txtamount" + this.id).val();